# JS for loop to fill array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Good day all and happy b-lated new year

So I got a problem and I would rather not tie everything directly into an array and call it from there.  Im building an old school chat based RPG and I have hit an issue with passing on the skills which are determined by the characters stats.  Essentially what I am trying to do is this:

I have a bunch of buttons which represent a total of 72 skills:

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="" class="button" id="math">MATH</button></td>
```

which I would like to use their onclick event to pass both the skill name and skill rating to this targeted area of the page:

```
<td><input type="text" id="skill1"     value="" readonly /></td>
<td><input type="text" id="skillRate1" value="" readonly /></td>
```

the skillRate(s) are reflected in their appropriate variables like so:

```
var math = (mem * 3) + (log * 2);
```

and ideally what will happen is I set each targeted recipient in an array as skill and skillRate respectively so that once all the skills are selected it is stored in the array and uploaded into the DB as such.

Originally I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
function addSkill(){
  var n = 0;
  for (n = 0; n < 17; n++){
    getElementById("skill" + n) = getElementById(this.id);
    getElementById("skillRate" + n) = //figure out some way to turn this into the var for skillRate (getElementById(this.id));
  }
}
```

I've been bumbling around with this for days now but cant seem to get anywhere and I would really rather not just put all the skills and their respective skillRates in an array unless I have to.

Any thoughts or suggestions as to how to accomplish this or maybe another approach altogether?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My recommendation would be to keep all the data on the JavaScript side, and use HTML only for presentation purposes, but seems like that's what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: If you want to stick with putting the data in the HTML, you may find the HTML data/dataset attributes helpful here.  Here's a primer https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but no I just want to user to see that they picked a skill when they click the button, so its just dropping the name and rate into the table under their skills list.  Im all for keeping the data in the JS file

Comment: I've added an answer, let me know if it is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you problem properly, maybe you can do it this way:

For html

```
<td>
  <button type="button" data-skill="math" data-point="20" onclick="addSkill(this)" class="button" id="math">MATH</button>
</td>
```

For javascript

```
//Start your variables
var tagsSkills = []
var totalPoint = 0;

function addSkill(skill) {
  var dataset = skill.dataset;
  totalPoint += dataset.point; // Here you will sum the skill's point
  tagsSkills.push(dataset.skill); // Add skill into array
}
```

Or maybe, instead you could use a map structure that store map[skill] to points. And, just with skill in the function, you will have the points just getting it from the map.

Comment: I was looking at the data-* option but its my understanding that its only allowed to have strings?  I guess even then I could just do a parse right?  Anyway I feel like this is what Im looking for but theres no need for sum.  The math skill has a rate thats = `var math = (mem * 3) + (log * 2);` so then could I just set `dataset.point = math;` ?

Comment: Yah, just parse it to integer, if it is necessary. My sum operations was just an example. In your case, you could set iterating over document.getElementByTagName('button") array, for example, setting every element with element.dataset.point = math. `var elements = document.getElementByTagName('button") for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){ // Some operations here elements[i].dataset.point = math; }`

Comment: it is better you set a class called 'skills-button', for example, and getting it by  `document.getElementByClassName('skills-button')`. Just to avoid conflict with others button within the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't want array, they are your friends.

This code will build a table from array but only uses it for build, all the calculations are later taken from html.

This is vanilla js, could be easier/prettier with jQuery.

JS:

```
//This is just for building the table, you don't have to use it if you don't want array for some reason :S
var skillsArr = [{
  firstSkillName: "Memory",
  firstSkillValue: 15,
  secondSkillName: "Logic",
  secondSkillValue: 17
}, {
  firstSkillName: "Dexterity",
  firstSkillValue: 12,
  secondSkillName: "Speedness",
  secondSkillValue: 11
}];

var table = document.getElementById("tblSKills");
var tableBody = table.createTBody();

for (i = 0; i < skillsArr.length; i++) {
  var row = tableBody.insertRow(i);
  var cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = skillsArr[i].firstSkillName + ": " + "<span>" + skillsArr[i].firstSkillValue + "</span>";
  cell = row.insertCell(1);
  cell.innerHTML = skillsArr[i].secondSkillName + ": " + " <span>" + skillsArr[i].secondSkillValue + "</span>";
  cell = row.insertCell(2);
  cell.innerHTML = "<button onclick='doMath(this)'>DO THE MATH</button>";
}

function doMath(currnetBtn) {  
  var currentRow = currnetBtn.parentElement.parentElement; //TD -> TR
  var currentCells = currentRow.children;

  var skill1 = document.getElementById("skill1");
  var skill2 = document.getElementById("skill2");
  var mathResult = document.getElementById("mathResult");

  skill1.value = currentCells[0].innerText;
  skill2.value = currentCells[1].innerText;

  mathResult.value = (currentCells[0].children[0].innerText/1) * 3 + (currentCells[1].children[0].innerText/1) *2 ;//This is your *3 + *2 function or whatever you want.
  //You can also make that each skill set will have its' own math function.
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
Welcome to my skill page!
</h1>
<h2>
Your results:
</h2>
<label id="lbl1"></label>
<input id="skill1" readonly />
<label id="lbl2"></label>
<input id="skill2" readonly />
<label>Result:</label>
<input id="mathResult" readonly />

<table id="tblSKills">

</table>
```

[-- Fiddle --](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Ln1jydwp/1/)